# Is the deep ocean fish look ugly because due to darkness there is no visual sexual selection?

Tags: zoology, ichthyology, sexual-selection

Is the deep ocean fish look ugly because due to darkness there is no visual sexual selection? If so, is there a common notion of beauty between humans and animals?

Comment: Probably your query will be unresolved, but in researching deep water fish courting you will find info like: 
they engage in parasitic mating, they digest their own face and whatever part of the female they’re latched on to via teeth so that they can become fused at a tissue level ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhsyZnVx2rQ perhaps best rephrase like: why do deep water fish have completely different and ugly facial proportions compared to most other vertebrates? Is it because they can't see each other.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the deep ocean fish look ugly to you because they are unfamiliar.  The iconic fish species with which humans have coexisted forever are all surface fish, with common adaptations for surface living in the light.  When one thinks of a fish the salmon or cod is what we think of.

The deep fish have different selection pressures.  They do not need to be streamlined or svelte.  A deep fish might think a surface fish is ugly because it cannot make its own light - how plain and dull.  How can the surface worlders find a good mate if everyone is dark?

Comment: The peacocks are also unfamiliar to me, yet their looks seems festive nevertheless. http://mirplaneta.ru/images/2/412.jpg

Comment: good info, they often swim slowly and have low energy so they are less streamlined. The goblin shark swims quite fast though and it is also one of the most strange of all sharks.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYpn2u2Wag4 .... https://www.google.com/search?q=goblin+shark&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib47mA0-bgAhWQERQKHZ1bAGIQ_AUIDigB&biw=1431&bih=734#imgrc=AdlcEl7MK3cpcM:

Comment: @Anixx: Perhaps peacocks look beautiful to you, but how about vultures?  Yet both must be attractive to the opposite sex of their species, no?

Comment: @jamesqf perhaps in vultures looks plays less role in sexual attraction than obtaining resources?